# Diffing two variables in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script that has the following line

```
diff <(echo "$var_1") <(echo "$var_2")
```

both variables could contain new lines so there, at least from my own understanding, must be "" around the echo statements. However no matter if I escape the "s or not bash continues to say there is an error.

```
/cygdrive/c/foo/compare_dirs.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/cygdrive/c/foo/compare_dirs.sh: line 15: `diff <(echo "$var_1") <(echo "$var_2")'
```

However if I paste that line into cygwin it works?!???!!

Comment: Your current shell is not BASH or very old version of BASH

Comment: Your script compare_dirs.sh does not use a bash or a very old version.

Comment: Would running it on cygwin be why? Also what is indicative of it being a very old version?

Comment: What is the first line in your `compare_dirs.sh` script?

Comment: #!/bin/sh
make the comment longer.......

Comment: And what if you were to make that line `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: Or, the actual error is on a previous line, for example a missing bracket.  Remember that line numbers are where the error was *detected*, not necessarily where it occurred.

Comment: @chrisaycock It works! Ok wth? Why wasn't it working before?

Comment: @Zimm3r do `/bin/bash --version` and `/bin/sh --version` - what's the output of those?

Comment: @ap same output; 4.3.39(2) GNU Bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed-out in the comments (hat tip to @anubhava), the OP isn't using bash for the actual script. The shebang must be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

to use the correct shell.